# SQL Server - Using declared variable to identify pivot columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL Server Pivot Query that I created to pivot and display the rates and prices for a lenders that meet certain parameters.  This query works great but the problem is that I must manually identify and type in the rates (which become the column names) I want to use for each separate query I create.

I would like to be able to simply declare a variable that searches the table and identifies the minimum rate for that product grouping and then use that variable to identify the columns I want to pivot upon.

I have created the variable and it successful finds the correct rate, but when I go to replace the column(rates) names from "[4],[4.125],..." to "[@RateMIN],[@RateMIN2],...etc" I get an error complaining that: "Error converting data type nvarchar to float."

The strange thing is that the Rate column is already a float, so why is it trying to convert it form nvarchar to float?  I figure there must some aspect of the pivot function that I am not taking into account or not understanding?

Per Request, adding the query that works now, but doesn't have the variable.

```
DECLARE @ProductX as VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @statenameX as VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @purposeTypeX as VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ficoX as float
DECLARE @loanSizeX as float
DECLARE @LTVx as float

SET @ProductX = '30YearFixedProduct'
SET @statenameX = 'CA'
SET @purposeTypeX = 'Purchase'
SET @ficoX = 740
SET @loanSizeX = 900000
SET @LTVx = 70

SELECT
LenderName as 'Lenders',
[4] as '4.000%',
[4.125] as '4.125%',
[4.25] as '4.250%',
[4.375] as '4.375%',
[4.5] as '4.500%',
[4.625] as '4.625%',
[4.75] as '4.750%',
[4.875] as '4.875%'




from
(
    SELECT 
    [LenderName],[Price],[Rate]
    FROM
    PricingTable

    WHERE
    Product = @ProductX AND
    statename = @statenameX AND
    PurposeType = @purposeTypeX AND
    FICO = @ficoX AND 
    LoanSize = @loanSizeX AND
    LTV = @LTVx


) as SourceTable2

Pivot
(
avg(Price) for Rate IN ([4],[4.125],[4.25],[4.375],[4.5],[4.625],[4.75],[4.875])
)
as PivotTable2

Order by 
CASE WHEN [4.125] is null then 1 else 0 end, 
[4.125]
```

Adding Query where I try to add the variable @RateMin and use it to define one of the column names.  This query below is the one that gives me the error.

```
DECLARE @ProductX as VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @statenameX as VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @purposeTypeX as VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ficoX as float
DECLARE @loanSizeX as float
DECLARE @LTVx as float

DECLARE @rateMIN as float
SET @rateMIN = (SELECT min([rate])   FROM PricingTable  WHERE 
            Product = @ProductX AND 
            statename = @statenameX AND 
            PurposeType = @purposeTypeX AND
            FICO = @ficoX AND 
            LoanSize = @loanSizeX AND
            LTV = @LTVx)


SET @ProductX = '30YearFixedProduct'
SET @statenameX = 'CA'
SET @purposeTypeX = 'Purchase'
SET @ficoX = 740
SET @loanSizeX = 900000
SET @LTVx = 70

SELECT
LenderName as 'Lenders',
[@rateMIN] as '4.000%',
[4.125] as '4.125%',
[4.25] as '4.250%',
[4.375] as '4.375%',
[4.5] as '4.500%',
[4.625] as '4.625%',
[4.75] as '4.750%',
[4.875] as '4.875%'

from
(
    SELECT 
    [LenderName],[Price],[Rate]
    FROM
    PricingTable

    WHERE
    Product = @ProductX AND
    statename = @statenameX AND
    PurposeType = @purposeTypeX AND
    FICO = @ficoX AND 
    LoanSize = @loanSizeX AND
    LTV = @LTVx


) as SourceTable2

Pivot
(
avg(Price) for Rate IN ([@rateMIN],[4.125],[4.25],[4.375],[4.5],[4.625],[4.75],[4.875])
)
as PivotTable2

Order by 
CASE WHEN [4.125] is null then 1 else 0 end, 
[4.125]
```

Comment: Can you post the query, or at least a representative sample of it?

Comment: Well, if `@RateMIN` is actually a `FLOAT` you can't concatenate it with a string directly. Also, it seems like what you are looking for is a dynamic pivot

Comment: +1 with the dynamic pivot approach. There are a few different ways to approach it, a search for "dynamic pivot" on SO gives a nice variety of examples.

Comment: I will have to research more into the dynamic pivot approach.  I am just having trouble conceptualizing how I would use it to solve this issue.  I have seen example of that approach but never actually used it.  
  
 Why can I not just turn the variable into a string?  Would that not be interpreted exactly the same as me typing in the number 4?

Comment: Suppose you have a sandwich in a zip lock, you cannot eat it without taking the sandwich out of the zip lock unless you like the taste of zip lock :). Same principle applies here.

Comment: That is an interesting metaphor! :)  However, by taking a float variable and converting it into a string, wouldn't I be taking it out of the zip lock and thereby eating the sandwich only?

Comment: I think I figured it out with the dynamic query solution.  Let me finish working it out and then I will post the solution in case anyone else comes across a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well I finally figured it out and so I am coming back here to post the results so others can benefit from my experience.

The most important thing I learned was that, when creating and testing dynamic SQL, DO NOT try to simply execute the query.  When you are building such a query you need to first PRINT it.  Then you take the results and copy and paste them into a new query window.  THAT will allow you to see what is actually being concatenated and where you are running into issues!  I didn’t see this recommendation anywhere online.

The next biggest issue I had was that I ran needed to take a different approach with my column names.  I had to use the COALESCE statement with QUOTENAME from a tutorial I found on the internet.  This series of statements finds the available values for rate in my pricing table and then translates them into the text that I use to build my SQL statement.

I still feel like having to use dynamic SQL is a bit backwards compared to other programming I have done.  Why do I need to turn my entire select statement into text?  Why not simply keep it as it is and then turn the variables into text and then have SQL run that?  I will have to think about this a bit.  I must not understand some intricacy of how SQL handles/runs queries.

Here is the completed dynamic SQL query which works.  Notice that I am printing the result, but I could just as easily execute it:

```
DECLARE @ProductX as VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @stateX as VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @PurposeX as VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ficoX as NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @loanSizeX as NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @LTVx as NVARCHAR(MAX)
Declare @RateX NVARCHAR(MAX)
Declare @RateX_2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
declare @SQL as NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Columns as VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @ProductX = '30YearFixedProduct'
SET @stateX = 'CA'
SET @PurposeX = 'Purchase'
SET @ficoX = 740
SET @loanSizeX = 900000
SET @LTVx = 70

SELECT @Columns = COALESCE(@Columns + ',','') + QUOTENAME(RATE)
                    FROM
                      (
                      SELECT DISTINCT RATE
                      FROM PricingTable WHERE
                        Product = @ProductX AND
                        state = @stateX AND
                        Purpose = @PurposeX AND
                        FICO = @ficoX AND 
                        LoanSize = @loanSizeX AND
                        LTV = @LTVx) 
                       AS TableNew


set @RateX = (select min(rate) from PricingTable    WHERE
                        Product = @ProductX AND
                        state = @stateX AND
                        Purpose = @PurposeX AND
                        FICO = @ficoX AND 
                        LoanSize = @loanSizeX AND
                        LTV = @LTVx)

set @RateX_2 = cast(@RateX as float) + .125





SET @SQL = '
SELECT
Lenders,
'+@Columns+'


from
(
    SELECT 
    [Lenders],[Price],[Rate]
    FROM
    PricingTable

    WHERE
    Product = '''+@ProductX+''' AND
    state = '''+@stateX+''' AND
    Purpose = '''+@PurposeX+''' AND
    FICO = '''+@ficoX+''' AND 
    LoanSize = '''+@loanSizeX+''' AND
    LTV = '''+@LTVx+'''


) as SourceTable2

Pivot
(
avg(Price) for Rate IN ('+@Columns+')
)
as PivotTable2


'
PRINT (@SQL)
```